# Debugging GCC compile times

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm creating a fairly large library in [C++0x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) using GCC 4.6 in Linux. My library relies heavily on template classes, resulting in long compile times for applications which use the library. I would like to start speeding things up by providing explicit instantiations of the worst offending types/methods.

Is there a way to have GCC report the time spent compiling various types/methods so that I can apply my explicit instantiations in a principled way, rather than through intuition?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*g++ some_file.cc [-ftime-report](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-ftime-report)* will give you a rough estimate of time spent in different compiler phases. The most important ones in your case are name lookup and parsing.

There isn’t any way to get a per class/function compile time alas.

Steven Watanabe has proposed a template profiler, available in the [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) sandbox that helps getting the number of potential instantiation of anything in a *.cc* file.

UPDATE AFTER 12 YEARS:

Most of these solutions are out-dated.
Look at https://github.com/aras-p/ClangBuildAnalyzer for a modern take.

Comment: said profiler link :
https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/tools/profile_templates/

Comment: This would be more useful if there were any semblance of docs on how to use it.

Comment: @xaxxon There's a 'doc' folder :)

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use it based on just the docs folder. Steven's original post has a little more context: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Profiling-template-instantiations-td2657157.html

Comment: FTR: now that the original repo is gone, at least (a fork of) it can be seen at GitHub: https://github.com/psiha/profile_templates2 (which is itself abandonware for over a decade :) ). Any better pointer on this topic, BTW? E.g. has it perhaps been a compiler feature somewhere since then?

Comment: Nowadays using https://github.com/aras-p/ClangBuildAnalyzer is better. Shoudl I edit the original post ?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's not what you're looking for, but maybe *[ccache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ccache)* or *[distcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distcc)* may help to speed up compilation.

Also if you have a multicore machine you may exploit *make -jN* to tell Make run *N* jobs at once.

Don't forget about *precompiled headers* too.

Comment: Fortunately, I have server farm on which I compile - However, I'm trying to make things faster for any poor user that wants to compile all of these crazy templates.